# C# Zoomed image in Picturebox gets cropped in top left

Tags: c#, zooming, crop, picturebox

I want to make  very simplistic paint/image editor. Mainly, for pixel editing, but that doesn't seem relevant.
To ease up my effort, I decided to keep the image size at 16x16.

I populate the form, add a [PixelBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/717312/PixelBox-A-PictureBox-with-configurable-Interpolat) and slap a default image on it.
Of course, I need to make the pixels visible, set the interpolation to NearestNeighbor.

Then, I stretch the pixelbox to 320x320. And there the situation arises.

The image is displayed as thus:
[Cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmXXd.png)

Could someone shed some light on this? This is just a 16x16 image with a checkerboard pattern that I made, but I can't figure out why it is displayed with that offset at the top left.

Also, no code as been yet added. I assume this is default behavior?

Comment: Kinda late, but if you still haven't figured it out... set `g.PixelOffsetMode` to `PixelOffsetMode.Half`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the examples on the page that exact same error happens, so it must be a bug on the PixelBox.

Instead of using a custom control for this type of operation just use the standard PictureBox and scale the image by yourself:

```
    public Bitmap ScaleBitmap(Bitmap src, Size NewSize)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(NewSize.Width, NewSize.Height, src.PixelFormat);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(src);
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, NewSize), new Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        g.Dispose();
        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Gusman. Sorry for the late reply.Thanks for the help. It kind of works. The offset still happens. I'll mark your answer because it makes valid points and has good info. It seems the resize starts from the middle of the top-left pixel...